# iOS Safariで複数のselectが存在するときの挙動

Tags: ios, html

例えば、以下のような年月日を選択するような入力欄があったして、

```html
<select name="year">
    <option value="0">--</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="2001">2001</option>
    <option value="2002">2002</option>
    <option value="2003">2003</option>
</select>年
<select name="month">
    <option value="0">--</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>月
<select name="day">
    <option value="0">--</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>日
```

左から順番に選択していくとします。

ここで完了を押さずに他のセレクトボックスをタップすると一個前で選択していた項目がx番目だったとして、現在フォーカスがあったているセレクトボックスのx番目の項目が選択されます。本当は一個前のセレクトボックスが選択されて欲しいのですが、この問題を解決する方法はあるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

タップするものにclickイベントを設定して、そのイベントでフォーカスを移動するという処理をjavascriptで実装すれば良いと思います。

Answer (score 1):

iOSでは通称ドラムロールが出て、左上にprev nextアイコン（＜　＞）でtabindexがついたフォーム部品を番号昇順にフォーカスします。多くのユーザがその操作をしているとある企業のUX担当がいってます。
また`tabindex=-1`で除外ができます。

で、ドラムロールが出て、完了も押さずに次のフォームをタップすることはあると思いますが、form要素とtabindexをきちっとつくって、それでも無理ならJavaScriptでイベントをリスニングする必要があると思います。

また、経験上、optgroupはiOSでよくわからない挙動（複数選択ができてしまったり）をすることがあります。

Answer (score -1):

tabindex でうまく制御できません？

Comment: `tabindex` をどう使えば、問題が解決するのか、具体的に示す、例えばコードで説明すると、良い回答とされるはずです。ヘルプの「[回答にあたって](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/answering)」が参考に編集してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: はい、承知しました。もう一度回答してみます。

Comment: 回答を良くする場合は、別回答の投稿ではなく、編集での改善でよいですよ。 投稿されてしまったのは仕方ありませんね・・・ マイナス投票を入れたのは私ではありませんので、取り消せないのですが、とりあえず +1 しました。

Comment: あ、そうでしたか。ありがとうございます、いろいろ